# Can I alt-tab while dragging a chrome tab?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, google-chrome, window-management

I'm a newb ubuntu user, coming from Windows. On Windows, I could pick up one chrome <kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to find another chrome window, and place it there.

I find that this doesn't work on ubuntu/gnome. Can it be made to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alt-Tab does not seem to work in Ubuntu/Unity (Compiz) during Drag'n'Drop:

[Drag and Drop across (fullscreen) applications, switching via Alt-Tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37335/drag-and-drop-across-fullscreen-applications-switching-via-alt-tab)

Comment: Yes, just confirmed. Alt-Tab doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can. Same way as you are mentioning here. Already tried on Chrome 10, 11 and 12-Dev.

I even had 4 Chrome windows opened. Picked a chrome tab and that puppy started going/dragging from one windows to another. I recommend making sure you have ubuntu up to date (Using 10.10 here) and Chrome also updated (They make an update every 3 to 7 days).

BTW I did not know of this until you asked. Thanks for the trick which i confirm works on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 10.04.2 and Chrome 11.0.696.38, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 and Chrome 10.0.648.204, dual monitor, 2 workspaces. What @CYREX says seems not to work even if all the chrome windows are in the same workspace. No Alt-Tab, neither Super-Tab.

Comment: Then there must be another problem since i have 3 PCs right here. 1 has the exact version you have 10.0.648.204 the other 2 have version 11 and 12. Am trying it right now and they all can ALT+TAB while draggin a tab from any of the chrome windows. Your question is in regard if you can ALT+TAB while dragging a chrome tab and yes you can. Remove the dual monitor and 2 workspaces and try it again

Comment: Tried to CTRL+ALT+Right Arrow to another workspace with the tab of chrome dragged. Worked also. This only leaves the dual monitor configuration and Using Ubuntu 10.04.2

Comment: Tried Dual Monitor with an Epson in 2 of the PCs. It Worked again. This only leaves the 10.04.2 version but i wont go that far for test.